# Get session outside application (Symfony)

Tags: php, symfony, session

I created a php file in \web folder (that's mean outside of the application right?), I set a variable in a session within the application (in a controller action), but I can't get that session outside the application (in the external php file). I got always empty session.

this is the controller's action where I set the session

```
 */
public function questionnaireConfigAction($id,Request $request)
{
    $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $questionTypes=$em->getRepository(QuestionType::class)->findAll();
    $questionnaire = $em->getRepository(Questionnaire::class)->find($id);
    $session = new Session();
    $session->set('fileContext',['questionTypes'=>$questionTypes,'questionnaire'=>$questionnaire]);
    return $this->render('questionnaires/questionnaireConfig/config.html.twig',
        ['questionTypes'=>$questionTypes,
         'questionnaire'=>$questionnaire]);
}
```

and here is the external file

```
 use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use AppBundle\twigExtentions\filesLoader;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\PhpBridgeSessionStorage;
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../app/autoload.php';

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$session = new Session();
$session->start();
dump($session->get('fileContext')); /*get nothing here */
```

Comment: Have you verified whether the session id is available to your second script …?

Comment: with $session->getId() ? yes and i got the same id of the first script

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]
i find the solution .  by using PhpBridgeSessionStorage class

```
ini_set('session.save_handler', 'files');
ini_set('session.save_path', 'path/to/save file');
session_start();
$session = new Session(new PhpBridgeSessionStorage());
$session->start();

dump($session->get('fileContext'));
```

[here the symfony doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_php_bridge.html)